# Matrix block expression

Tags: matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

Let's say I have $\widehat{\sigma} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 1}$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 1}$, $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 1}$, $k \in \mathbb{R}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $H \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$

Is the following equation true?

$$\widehat{\sigma}^T H X - kc\sigma^T X = \begin{pmatrix}
    \widehat{\sigma} \\
    k
    \end{pmatrix}^T
    \begin{pmatrix}
    H \\
    -c \sigma^T
    \end{pmatrix}
    X.$$
I mean, the dimensions are correct, because both sides are numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's true. To parse things out, note that for a block matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}A_1 \\ A_2\end{bmatrix}$ with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $A_1\in\mathbb{R}^{m_1\times n}$, $A_2\in\mathbb{R}^{m_2\times n}$, and $m_1+m_2=m$, we have that
\begin{equation*}
Ax = \begin{bmatrix}A_1 \\ A_2\end{bmatrix}x = \begin{bmatrix}A_1x \\ A_2x\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
for a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. (Convince yourself of this by checking dimensions, computing a simple example, or by writing out the actual multiplication.) Therefore, in your example,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
H \\ -c\sigma^\top
\end{bmatrix}X = \begin{bmatrix}
HX \\ -c\sigma^\top X
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation*}
which is a $(p+1)\times 1$ vector. Left multiplying by the transpose of your other $(p+1)\times 1$ vector with the same block dimensions, we obtain
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\sigma} \\ k
\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix}
HX \\ -c\sigma^\top X
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\sigma}^\top & k
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
HX \\ -c\sigma^\top X
\end{bmatrix} = \hat{\sigma}^\top Hx - kc\sigma^\top X.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you so much!